# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s);

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

This exception comes when I update my entity. And sometime entity is updated successfully.

Here is my table entity configurations:

Using EF Core and MySQL as database.

1. Table 1: `ParentEntity` (`Id` is primary key and auto-incremented)
2. Table 2: `ChildEntity` (`CId` is primary key and auto-incremented, Parent entity Id as foreign key).
3. Table 3: `SubChildEntity` (`SId` is primary key and autoincremented, `CID` as foreign key).

Error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyExceptionAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, Int32 commandIndex, Int32 expectedRowsAffected, Int32 rowsAffected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeResultSetWithRowsAffectedOnlyAsync(Int32 commandIndex, RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Code:

```
var Entity = await _context.Parent
                           .Include(x => x.Child)
                           .ThenInclude(x => x.SubChild)
                           .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == Id, cancellationToken);

// Some values to update in parent, child and sub child entities.
_context.Parent.Update(Entity);

var result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: And could the exception be correct because the data has changes in the database?

Comment: @Ralf Even if i update the same entity with same data. It gives the same exception

Comment: How do you update the `Entity`? Can you show us some code, please?

Comment: Could you share your code of  the context ? It would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug this by wrapping your code in a try catch block. In the catch you can view the database values as well as your proposed updates. This is covered in [Handling Concurrency Conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations#resolving-concurrency-conflicts).

For example:

```
try {
  //Your original code
  var Entity = await _context.Parent
                           .Include(x => x.Child)
                           .ThenInclude(x => x.SubChild)
                           .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == Id, cancellationToken);

  // Some values to update in parent, child and sub child entities.
  _context.Parent.Update(Entity);

  var result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
{
    //The code from Microsoft - Resolving concurrency conflicts 
    foreach (var entry in ex.Entries)
    {
        if (entry.Entity is Person)
        {
            var proposedValues = entry.CurrentValues; //Your proposed changes
            var databaseValues = entry.GetDatabaseValues(); //Values in the Db

            foreach (var property in proposedValues.Properties)
            {
                var proposedValue = proposedValues[property];
                var databaseValue = databaseValues[property];

                // TODO: decide which value should be written to database
                // proposedValues[property] = <value to be saved>;
            }

            // Refresh original values to bypass next concurrency check
            entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(databaseValues);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(
                "Don't know how to handle concurrency conflicts for "
                + entry.Metadata.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Compare your proposedValue to the databaseValue to view the differences and what might be causing the conflict.

My hunch, from the info provided, is that you are calling the same function multiple times concurrently if it is used in a web api or some other multithreaded app (or maybe with some kind of retry library like Polly). Count how many times the function is called to verify.